# How can I detect which user is the sender of a message from an iOS iMessage extension?

Tags: ios, swift, imessage

I recently started work on my iMessage extension for my app.

If one user sends the message and the other will receive it, how can I receive data from the user who sent the message and change my UI accordingly? The data is only a string. I am not sure how to to detect if the `activeMessage` was from the sender or the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

A [`MSMessage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msmessage) has a property `var senderParticipantIdentifier: UUID` that will give you the UUID of message author. That information can be compared to the [`MSConversation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msconversation) information. The  [`MSConversation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msconversation) has properties for `var localParticipantIdentifier: UUID`

> A UUID that identifies the user on this device.

and `var remoteParticipantIdentifiers: [UUID]`

> An array of UUIDs representing the remote participants in this
> conversation.

There is a great deal of available info in the [Docs for the Messages framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages).